# Autofocus Sigma 17-70 Macro OS HSM not working on D3300

Tags: nikon, autofocus, sigma, nikon-d3300

I've purchased a used Sigma 17-70mm f/2.8-4 DC OS HSM for my Nikon D3300. It appears to work fine, with one exception: the autofocus. I've checked the switch on the lens and it is set to AF. However, no autofocus seems to happen when clicking the shutter release button. The display of the DSLR shows the focus mode constantly switching between AF and MF.

I've searched for issues with this combination but I could only find a firmware issue with the D5300 and some of these Sigma lenses, and I'm not sure if that should affect my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the suggestions Frank posted and got a D5000 to test the lens on. It performed well, as did other lenses on my D3300. I contacted Sigma and they told me that it's likely an issue with the firmware on the lens and that I could send the lens their way so they can upgrade it.

I also found this compatibility chart, which should be helpful for anyone who's not sure if their Sigma lens of choice is compatible with their body: https://www.sigma-global.com/en/lenses/cas/product/popups/lenses-correspondencelist/

Answer (score 3):

The lens has an AF motor, so it should work properly with Nikon's D3xxx series.

Try cleaning the contacts on the lens and body with a clean micro-fiber cloth.

Sometimes turning the camera off, then taking the lens off and then putting back on again can fix these kinds of issues.

You may even want to ensure that you're using the latest firmware version in your DSLR.

Take your camera to a local camera shop to have it checked out.

Do other lenses properly focus? If so, then it's a lens issue.

Does the lens focus properly on a different Nikon body?  If so, then it could be a incompatibility issue with your specific model of DSLR with it's specific firmware version.

If none of these suggestion fix your problem, then it's time to send the lens in for repair.

Comment: Sometimes updating a camera's firmware can be counterproductive in terms of getting it to work with older third party lenses. There have been cases where lenses worked fine until the camera's firmware was updated and then the third party lens no longer worked. While Nikon, as well as Canon, will occasionally update a firmware to deal with an issue with an older Nikon or Canon lens, I've never heard of either doing the same to solve an issue with a third party lens.